# error: ‘k’ undeclared here (not in a function) [solution.c] int data[k], front,rear;

Tags: c, data-structures, queue

The thing is I need to assign some size to the k, so I tried the following code,

```
typedef struct {
    int data[k], front,rear;
    
} MyCircularQueue;

MyCircularQueue* myCircularQueueCreate(int k) {
    printf("enter the size of queue");
    scanf("%d",&k);
}
```

But i got the following error,
`error: ‘k’ undeclared here (not in a function) [solution.c]      int data[k], front,rear;`
So how to solve this, or how to assign the size for K.
I am performing operation on queue using structure.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `data` as a pointer:

```
typedef struct {
    int *data;
    int front;
    int rear;
} MyCircularQueue;
```

Then allocate space for it dynamically using `malloc`.